# What is the correct usage of Phonegap's update script?

Tags: cordova

I am currently trying to upgrade my app's phonegap version from 2.7.0 to 2.9.0.

When I try running this command to upgrade:

```
sh update ~/development-tools/AndroidStudioProjects/DeskClock
```

I get thrown this:

```
update: 27: [: /home/sander/development-tools/AndroidStudioProjects/DeskClock: unexpected operator
update: 47: update: function: not found
```

I have also added these 2 to my PATH variable:

```
/home/sander/development-tools/android-studio/sdk/tools/
/home/sander/development-tools/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
```

What am I missing here?
The wiki is sparse in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the WWW folder, deleted the old app and rebuilt the new one with same parameters and pasted the WWW folder into there.